# How to address 'OSError: libc not found' raised on Gunicorn exec of Flask app inside Alpine docker container

Tags: python, docker, sockets, flask, gunicorn

I'm working on a Flask application based on the Microblog app from Miguel Grinberg's mega-tutorial. Code lives here: https://github.com/dnilasor/quickgig . I have a working docker implementation with a linked MySQL 5.7 container. Today I added an Admin View function using the Flask-Admin module. It works beautifully served locally (OSX) on Flask server via 'flask run' but when I build and run the new docker image (based on python:3.8-alpine), it crashes on boot with a `OSError: libc not found` error, the code for which seems to indicate [an unknown library](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/438371ee90b9676336a44c7abaeb30ee7fc57a5c/gunicorn/socketfromfd.py#L26)

It looks to me like Gunicorn is unable to serve the app following my additions. My classmate and I are stumped!

I originally got the error using the python:3.6-alpine base image and so tried with 3.7 and 3.8 to no avail. I also noticed that I was redundantly adding PyMySQL, once in requirements.txt specifying version no. and again explicitly in the dockerfile with no spec. Removed the requirements.txt entry. Also tried incrementing the Flask-Admin version no. up and down. Also tried cleaning up my database migrations as I have seen multiple migration files causing the container to fail to boot (admittedly this was when using SQLite). Now there is only a single migration file and based on the stack trace it seems like the `flask db upgrade` works just fine.

One thing I have yet to try is a different base image (less minimal?), can try soon and update this. But the issue is so mysterious to me that I thought it time to ask if anyone else has seen it : )

I did find [this socket bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue28134) which seemed potentially relevant but it was supposed to be fully fixed in python 3.8.

Also FYI I followed some of the advice [here](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/microblog/issues/49) on circular imports and imported my admin controller function inside `create_app`.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

RUN adduser -D quickgig

WORKDIR /home/quickgig

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python -m venv venv
RUN venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN venv/bin/pip install gunicorn pymysql

COPY app app
COPY migrations migrations
COPY quickgig.py config.py boot.sh ./
RUN chmod +x boot.sh

ENV FLASK_APP quickgig.py

RUN chown -R quickgig:quickgig ./
USER quickgig

EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["./boot.sh"]
```

boot.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
source venv/bin/activate
while true; do
    flask db upgrade
    if [[ "$?" == "0" ]]; then
        break
    fi
    echo Upgrade command failed, retrying in 5 secs...
    sleep 5
done
# flask translate compile
exec gunicorn -b :5000 --access-logfile - --error-logfile - quickgig:app
```

Implementation in **init**.py:

```
from flask_admin import Admin
app_admin = Admin(name='Dashboard')

def create_app(config_class=Config):
  app = Flask(__name__)
  app.config.from_object(config_class)
...
  app_admin.init_app(app)

...
  from app.admin import add_admin_views
  add_admin_views()
...
  return app

from app import models
```

admin.py:

```
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from app.models import User, Gig, Neighborhood
from app import db
# Add views to app_admin

def add_admin_views():
    from . import app_admin
    app_admin.add_view(ModelView(User, db.session))
    app_admin.add_view(ModelView(Neighborhood, db.session))
    app_admin.add_view(ModelView(Gig, db.session))
```

requirements.txt:

```
alembic==0.9.6
Babel==2.5.1
blinker==1.4
certifi==2017.7.27.1
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
dominate==2.3.1
elasticsearch==6.1.1
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Admin==1.5.4
Flask-Babel==0.11.2
Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.7.1
Flask-Login==0.4.0
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-Migrate==2.1.1
Flask-Moment==0.5.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
guess-language-spirit==0.5.3
idna==2.6
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
Mako==1.0.7
MarkupSafe==1.0
PyJWT==1.5.3
python-dateutil==2.6.1
python-dotenv==0.7.1
python-editor==1.0.3
pytz==2017.2
requests==2.18.4
six==1.11.0
SQLAlchemy==1.1.14
urllib3==1.22
visitor==0.1.3
Werkzeug==0.14.1
WTForms==2.1
```

When I run the container in interactive terminal I see the following stack trace:

```
(venv) ****s-MacBook-Pro:quickgig ****$ docker run -ti quickgig:v7
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade  -> 1f5feeca29ac, test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/quickgig/venv/bin/gunicorn", line 6, in <module>
    from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import run
  File "/home/quickgig/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 9, in <module>
    from gunicorn.app.base import Application
  File "/home/quickgig/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 12, in <module>
    from gunicorn.arbiter import Arbiter
  File "/home/quickgig/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 16, in <module>
    from gunicorn import sock, systemd, util
  File "/home/quickgig/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 14, in <module>
    from gunicorn.socketfromfd import fromfd
  File "/home/quickgig/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/socketfromfd.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise OSError('libc not found')
OSError: libc not found
```

I'd like the app to boot/be served by gunicorn inside the container so I can continue developing with my team using the docker implementation and leveraging dockerized MySQL vs the pain of local MySQL for development. Can you advise?

Answer (score 8):

In your Dockerfile:

```
RUN apk add binutils libc-dev
```

Comment: This seems to work.  Unfortunately, it dramatically increases the size of the image.

Comment: Thanks!  I edited to just include binutils and libc-dev, making the image smaller.  I don't know what needs binutils, but it seems to be pivotal.

Answer (score 4):

Yes **Gunicorn 20.0.0** requires the package **libc-dev**.

So this works for me:

```
RUN apk --no-cache add libc-dev
```

Comment: I wanted this to work and tried it first (hate downgrading/specifying explicit versions) but it didn't : (

Answer (score 4):

This was an issue with gunicorn 20.0.0, tracked here:
https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/2160

The issue is fixed in 20.0.1 and forward. So, change this:

```
RUN venv/bin/pip install gunicorn pymysql
```

to this:

```
RUN venv/bin/pip install 'gunicorn>=20.0.1,<21' pymysql
```

---

If upgrading is not an option, as a workaround you can add the following line:

```
RUN apk --no-cache add binutils musl-dev
```

Unfortunately this adds about 20MB to the resulting docker container, but there isn't any other known workaround at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

This problem seems related to a new version of Gunicorn 20.0.0. Try to use a previous one 19.9.0

Comment: python3 ctypes.util.find_library('c') does not work correctly in python:alpine

Comment: Yep, `python3 -c "from ctypes.util import find_library; print(find_library('c'))"` returns `None`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem:

1. Dockerfile: remove this installation "RUN venv/bin/pip install
   gunicorn"
2. requirement.txt: add this line "gunicorn==19.7.1"

Comment: yup. used 19.9.0 but, yup